# What's the difference between tail and guarded recursion?

Tags: haskell, recursion, tail-recursion

In my exercise I have to decide what kind of recursion the functions are.

We have to choose from linear recursion, tail recursion and guarded recursion
but I don't really understand the difference between the last two.

Can some one explain the difference between guarded and tail recursion?

The functions we have to differentiate for reference:

```
pow2 0 = 1
pow2 n = 2 * pow2 (n-1)

factAux r i n
  | i <= n = factAux (i * r) (i + 1) n | otherwise = r
factorial = factAux 1 1

init [x] = []
init (x:xs) =  x : init xs

binom n 0 = 1
binom n k
  | n == k = 1
  | otherwise = binom (n - 1) k + binom (n - 1) (k - 1)

negList [] = []
negList (x : xs) = if x > 0 then negList (-x : xs) else x : negList xs
```

Comment: You should read [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166), Sure we could help you, but that would rob you of the education of doing it yourself.

Comment: to be clear: I dont want you to solve the problems, but I hope somebody could explain me the difference between guarded recursion and tail recursion:)

Comment: See [the Haskell Wiki on tail recursion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Tail_recursion).

Comment: In that case I'd remove the code (or at least the linearly recursive functions) since they are not relevant to the question.

Comment: @cafce25 Helping doesn't always rob of education. What we don't want to do is solve things for you. Your link says lots of stuff I agree with, I just don't think your one-sentence summary really does it justice.

Comment: @amalloy you're right, part of it is I misunderstood the question slightly, and yes I'm bad at words.

Answer (score 5):

I won't solve your homework as it would be counter-educative.

Instead, I will answer the question in the post's title:

### Tail recursion

A call is *tail-recursive* when

- It's recursive
- The result of that call is returned immediately, without any modification or action done after it

For example:

```hs
-- This is tail-rec
f x = if x == 0
      then 0
      else f (x + 1)

-- This is not
g x = if x == 0
      then 0
      else g (x + 1) - 1

-- And this is not too
h x = h (h x)
```

For more info, check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion).

### Guarded recursion

This occurs when a recursive call is positioned under a **lazy** parameter to a data constructor:

```hs
-- This is guarded-rec
f x = if x == 0
      then []
      else x : f (x - 1)  -- (:) is lazy on both operands

-- And this is not
g x = if x == 0
      then []
      else g (x - 1)

-- And this is not too
data StrictList a = SNil | SCons !a !(StrictList a)
h x = if x == 0
      then SNil
      SCons x (h x)
```

### Cross-examples

[This link](https://wiki.haskell.org/Tail_recursion) may help you seeing the difference. Also check out [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons), although it gives examples in Prolog.

#### Tail rec and guard rec

This is contradictory, as guarding a recursive call with a constructor breaks the "doing nothing to the result" requirement of tail recursion.

#### Tail rec and not guard rec

```hs
f x = f x
```

#### Not tail rec and guard rec

```hs
f x = x : f x
```

#### Not tail rec and not guard rec

```hs
f x = f x + 1
```